# How can I find matching string name in the same object and then add value that is contain on each of the matching property?

Tags: powershell, csv, grouping

I created a powershell command to collect and sort a txt file.

Input example:

```
a,1  
a,1  
b,3  
c,4  
z,5
```

The output that I have to get:

```
a,2  
b,3  
c,4  
z,5
```

Here is my code so far:

```
$filename = 'test.txt'
Get-Content $filename | ForEach-Object {
    $Line = $_.Trim() -Split ','
    New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
        Alphabet= $Line[0]
        Value= [int]$Line[1]
    }
}
```

example with negative value input

a,1,1
a,1,2
b,3,1
c,4,1
z,5,0

Comment: How does the input look like? can you provide an example of `test.txt` ?

Comment: sorry, my bad the output should be the input, im going to edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Import your text file as a CSV file using [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) with given column names (`-Header`), which parses the lines into objects with the column names as property names.
- Then use [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) to group the objects by shared `.Letter` values, i.e. the letter that is in the first field of each line.
- Using [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object), process each group of objects (lines), and output a single string that contains the shared letter and the sum of all `.Number` property values across the objects that make up the group, obtained via [`Measure-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object) `-Sum`:

```bash
@'
a,1
a,1
b,3
c,4
z,5
'@ > ./test.txt

Import-Csv -Header Letter, Number test.txt |
  Group-Object Letter |
  ForEach-Object {
    '{0},{1}' -f $_.Name, ($_.Group | Measure-Object -Sum -Property Number ).Sum
  }
```

Note: The above **OOP approach** is flexible, but potentially slow.
Here's a **plain-text alternative** that will likely perform better:

```bash
Get-Content test.txt |
  Group-Object { ($_ -split ',')[0] } |
  ForEach-Object {
    '{0},{1}' -f $_.Name, ($_.Group -replace '^.+,' | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
  }
```

See also:

- `-split`, the [string splitting operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split)
- `-replace`, the [regular-expression-based string replacement operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator)

---

**Grouping with summing of *multiple* fields:**

It is easy to extend the OOP approach: add another header field to name the additional column, and add another output field that sums that added column's values for each group too:

```bash
@'
a,1,10
a,1,10
b,3,30
'@ > ./test.txt

Import-Csv -Header Letter, NumberA, NumberB test.txt |
  Group-Object Letter |
  ForEach-Object {
    '{0},{1},{2}' -f $_.Name, 
                  ($_.Group | Measure-Object -Sum -Property NumberA).Sum, 
                  ($_.Group | Measure-Object -Sum -Property NumberB).Sum
  }
```

Output (note the values in the `a` line):

```bash
a,2,20
b,3,30
```

Extending the plain-text approach requires a bit more work:

```bash
@'
a,1,10
a,1,10
b,3,30
c,4,40
z,5,50
'@ > ./test.txt

Get-Content test.txt |
  Group-Object { ($_ -split ',')[0] } |
  ForEach-Object {
    '{0},{1},{2}' -f $_.Name, 
                  ($_.Group.ForEach({ ($_ -split ',')[1] }) | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum, 
                  ($_.Group.ForEach({ ($_ -split ',')[2] }) | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

One way to go about this is using `Group-Object` for the count, and then replacing the current number after the comma with the count.

```
$filename = 'test.txt'
Get-Content $filename | Group-Object | 
    ForEach-Object -Process {
        if ($_.Count -ne 1) { 
            $_.Name -replace '\d',$_.Count 
        }
        else { 
            $_.Name 
        }    
}  | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header 'Alphabet','Value'
```

Comment: how should i implement it to my existing code, i also dont really understand how it works

Comment: @notepadalert32, are you looking for it to be output into a pscustomobject, or you only care about the results?

Comment: pscustomobject because the actual amount of the data (alphabet and value) will be around 1400 lines

Comment: @notepadalert32, I updated my post. What are you having trouble with on understanding how this works?

Comment: THANK YOU, i got it working working with the code above

Comment: You're missing a criterion to group by in your `Group-Object` call: grouping by the _whole lines_ in the input will not give you the desired grouping by each line's first field.

Comment: This is the second time I've pointed out what - to me - is a fundamental flaw in an answer of yours.
In the absence of feedback I ended up down-voting.
While it is your choice to ignore feedback, it seems to me that it is to everyone's detriment:
If you believe your answer to be useful to future readers, a down-vote signals the opposite.
If there is indeed a fundamental flaw in the answer and you let it stand as-is, it is nothing but an unhelpful distraction.
If you _engage in a dialogue_, there's at least a chance that a shared understanding will be reached, to everyone's benefit.

Comment: @mklement0, I promise you, it is not that serious. Im a grown man that doesn't live on this site looking for feedback on my posts. don't know if it's cause I'm new but I don't get notifications so I go on about my day. Assuming the number differs each time rather than it being 1 for A, I can see where it would be an issue. Your solution makes more sense as it's better safe than sorry, but I simply answered the question. Thx tho

Comment: I realize I did a poor job of explaining in what way your answer is broken, and I apologize for that: It works with the sample data given, but _only_ with that.
Any slight variation breaks the solution, which is the problem: the OP's intent is to _sum up the numbers_ in field 2 for all lines that _share the same field 1 value_.
Your solution _groups identical lines_ and reports the _count_ of lines in each group as field 2. For instance, changing the first line in the sample input
from `a,1` to `a,2` breaks your solution.